# Use date to display previous login

Tags: java, mysql, date

I have a java application which uses a MySql database. In my application I have a JInternalFrame, which I use to display the current user information, like "Logged in as: " and "Last Login: ".

```
    loggedInUserLabel.setText("Logged in as: ");
    getContentPane().add(loggedInUserLabel);
    loggedInUserLabel.setBounds(30, 30, 80, 30);

    loggedInUser.setText("Admin");
    getContentPane().add(loggedInUser);
    loggedInUser.setBounds(140, 30, 80, 30);

    lastLoginLabel.setText("Last Login:");
    getContentPane().add(lastLoginLabel);
    lastLoginLabel.setBounds(30, 60, 80, 30);

    lastLogin.setText("14-03-2015");
    getContentPane().add(lastLogin);
    lastLogin.setBounds(140, 60, 80, 30);
```

How can I set the date, which I currently have set to a dummy value "14-03-2015" in order to display my last login ? Is there a way to to this through MySql ?

UPDATE

I've created a new table to store some of the login details:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `last_login`(
`username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`date` varchar(20) NOT NULL
);
```

The place where the login takes place looks like this:

```
if (rs.next()) {
        if (rs.getString("usertype").equals("Admin")) {
            setLoggedInUser(userBox.getText());
            insertData();
            AdminMenu adminMenu = new AdminMenu();
            adminMenu.setVisible(true);
            setVisible(false);
        } else if (rs.getString("usertype").equals("Employee")) {
            setLoggedInUser(userBox.getText());
            insertData();
            EmployeeMenu employeeMenu = new EmployeeMenu();
            employeeMenu.setVisible(true);
            setVisible(false);
        }
```

Using the "insertData" Iinsert new data into my table, which looks like this

```
public static void insertData() {
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "pass";
    String schmea = "db";

    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String currentDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    try {
        Connection conn = MySql.getConnection(user, pass, "/" + schmea);

        try {
            String q = "insert into last_login(username,date) values(?,?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(q);
            stmt.setString(1, loggedInUser);
            stmt.setString(2, currentDate);
            stmt.execute();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But question: I use this code to retrieve the date from the DB

```
public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {

            String user = "root";
            String pass = "pass";
            String schema = "db";
            String loggedInUser = Login.getLoggedInUser();

            try {
                Connection conn = MySql.getConnection(user, pass, "/" + schema);

                try {
                    String q = "select date from last_login where username=?";
                    PreparedStatement stmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(q);
                    stmt.setString(1, loggedInUser);
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                    if (rs.next()) {
                        lastLogin.setText(rs.getString(1));
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Unable to retrieve information for user: " + loggedInUser + "!");
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error in Query: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error in Database Connection: " + ex.getMessage());
            }

        }
```

I know I always get back the current date for that user. How can I date the previous date for that user ?

Comment: you mean , lastLogin date comes from DB ?

Comment: No, I don't have a table to store this. I ask if that would be the besto option. I also thought like using an array in java where I always print the element at the [i-1] position which would be my last login (current would be at position [i])... Would this also work ?

Comment: If you wan't wish to store into DB then, it's fine to  store into array, which will live upto program execute.

Comment: Do you need accuracy on a day-level or millisecond? If I login twice per day, what is my previous login attempt? this date or some date before?

Comment: Well, I display the date in the form: `SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy H:m:s");` and save it in the DB asa a `varchar(20)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use Date-Time Types

Do not use strings for date-time values. Use date-time types for date-time values.

In Java 8 and later, use [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) types such as [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) (a moment on the timeline in UTC). If Java 8 technology is not available (Android etc.), then use the venerable [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

For transferring data in and out of database, use java.sql types such as [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html). Hopefully JDBC drivers will be updated to support java.time types directly, but until then use the `java.time`-`java.sql` conversion methods such as [`from( Instant )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#from-java.time.Instant-) and [`toInstant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toInstant--).

In your database, learn about its date-time types. The SQL spec defines a few types, but support for these varies widely. Some database such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) have [excellent date-time support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html). Some such as [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) have week support. Some such as [H2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) are in the middle. Study your database’s documentation carefully. Then experiment to be sure you understand its behaviors. Date-time work can be tricky.

I do not understand your use of a date-only without time-of-day for tracking logins. Why would your only care about logins at a granularity of an entire day? Also, date-only is vague as a date's definition varies by time zone. Normally we track such business data as date-time values in [UTC](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCoordinated_Universal_Time) time zone. Then, for presentation, adjust into a particular time zone expected/desired by the user.

## Example App

Below is the source code for a complete app that stores login attempts in a database. This app is contrived, designed for demonstration purposes not deployment. Use at your own risk.

The [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)) portion of your app is a big distraction. This example app is simpler, with no user interface. Each time you run the app’s `main` method it reports the previous login attempt and then makes a fresh attempt. The fresh attempt randomly picks a user name.

```
package com.example.logintracker;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Contrived app to demonstrate saving login attempts to a database.
 *
 * This source code available via the Free Public License 1.0.0. http://opensource.org/licenses/FPL-1.0.0
 *
 * @author Basil Bourque
 */
public class App {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        App app = new App ();

        // Report the most recent login attempt.
        Authenticator authenticator_Reporter = new Authenticator ();
        LoginAttempt loginAttempt_Recent = authenticator_Reporter.getMostRecentAttempt ();
        System.out.println ( "Recent loginAttempt: " + loginAttempt_Recent );

        // Attempt a login.
        Authenticator authenticator_Login = new Authenticator ();
        ArrayList<String> userNames = new ArrayList<> ( Arrays.asList ( "Wendy" , "Lisa" , "Jesse" , "Oliver" , "Jasmine" , "Jean-Luc" , "Jarrod" , "Evonne" , "Elise" ) ); // Pick a name at random.
        String userName = userNames.get ( new Random ().nextInt ( userNames.size () ) ); // From user-interface.
        String password = "pw"; // From user-interface.
        LoginAttempt loginAttempt_Now = authenticator_Login.authenticate ( userName , password );
        System.out.println ( "Fresh loginAttempt: " + loginAttempt_Now );
        if ( loginAttempt_Now.getSuccessful () ) {
            // Run the app for this user.
            // TODO: implement.
        } else {
            // Else block this user from running this app.
            // TODO: implement.
        }
    }
}
```

The `Authenticator` is the gateway to the main business logic.

```
package com.example.logintracker;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * The business logic for handling login attempts. Called by separate user interface code.
 *
 * This source code available via the Free Public License 1.0.0. http://opensource.org/licenses/FPL-1.0.0
 *
 * @author Basil Bourque
 *
 */
public class Authenticator {

    // User-interface makes this call to execute a user’s login attempt.
    public LoginAttempt authenticate ( String userName , String password ) {
        Boolean successful = Boolean.FALSE;

        // TODO: Add business logic to perform authentication. Hard-coded here to always succeed for this demonstration code.
        successful = Boolean.TRUE;
        LoginAttempt loginAttempt = new LoginAttempt ( userName , Instant.now () , successful , UUID.randomUUID () );

        // Remember this attempt.
        Persister persister = new Persister ();
        persister.saveLoginAttempt ( loginAttempt );

        return loginAttempt;
    }

    public LoginAttempt getMostRecentAttempt () {
        Persister persister = new Persister ();
        LoginAttempt loginAttempt = persister.fetchMostRecentLoginAttempt ();
        return loginAttempt;
    }

}
```

The data for each login attempt is stored is a simple `LoginAttempt` class, as [value objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object).

```
package com.example.logintracker;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 *
 * Value object holding the data describing each login attempt: who was the user, when attempted, was the login successful.
 *
 * This source code available via the Free Public License 1.0.0. http://opensource.org/licenses/FPL-1.0.0
 *
 * @author Basil Bourque
 *
 */
public class LoginAttempt {

    private String userName;
    private Instant whenAttempted;
    private Boolean successful;
    private UUID uuid = null;

    public LoginAttempt ( String userNameArg , Instant whenAttemptedArg , Boolean successfulArg , UUID uuidArg ) {
//        System.out.println ( "Constructor of LoginAttempt: " + whenAttemptedArg + " user: " + userNameArg );
        this.userName = userNameArg;
        this.whenAttempted = whenAttemptedArg;
        this.successful = successfulArg;
        this.uuid = uuidArg;
    }

    // Getters. Read-only object.
    public String getUserName () {
        return this.userName;
    }

    public Instant getWhenAttempted () {
        return this.whenAttempted;
    }

    public Boolean getSuccessful () {
        return this.successful;
    }

    public UUID getUuid () {
        return this.uuid;
    }

    // Override Object.
    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "LoginAttempt{ " + "userName=" + this.userName + " | whenAttempted=" + this.whenAttempted + " | successful=" + this.successful + " | uuid=" + this.uuid + " }";
    }

}
```

Those login attempts are stored in a basic SQL table.

```sql
CREATE TABlE IF NOT EXISTS login_attempt_
(
    uuid_ UUID DEFAULT RANDOM_UUID() PRIMARY KEY,
    when_written_ TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL,
    username_ VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(255) NOT NULL,
    when_attempted_ TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    success_ BOOLEAN NOT NULL
)
;
```

Every time this app runs, it checks for the existence of that table. If not found, the app automatically creates that table. The database containing that table and the database user & password are all created automatically as well. So just run this app to see the demo happen. No additional setup needed.

This example database uses the [`H2` database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)), a free-of-cost open-source pure-Java SQL database. H2 can be run either in embedded mode or in client/server mode. In this app we use embedded mode. In a Maven project, simply add a dependency for `com.h2database`.

The `Persister` class handles all interactions with the database, saving and retrieving the login attempts.

```
package com.example.logintracker;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * Handles all persisting of data to database or other storage mechanism. Called from other code handling business logic.
 *
 * This source code available via the Free Public License 1.0.0. http://opensource.org/licenses/FPL-1.0.0
 *
 * @author Basil Bourque
 *
 */
public class Persister {

    public void saveLoginAttempt ( LoginAttempt loginAttempt ) {
        // Get database connection.
        // Make prepared statement.
        // Transfer pieces of data from LoginAttempt into PreparedStatement.
        // Execute database transaction.

        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder ();
        sql.append ( "INSERT INTO login_attempt_ ( username_ , when_attempted_ , success_ , uuid_ ) " + " \n" );
        sql.append ( "VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? )" + " \n" );
        sql.append ( ";" + " \n" );

        try ( Connection conn = this.fetchConnection (); ) {
//            System.out.println ( "conn: " + conn );

            try ( PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement ( sql.toString () ); ) {
                ps.setString ( 1 , loginAttempt.getUserName () );
                java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from ( loginAttempt.getWhenAttempted () );  // Converting from java.time.Instant to java.sql.Timestamp.
                ps.setTimestamp ( 2 , ts );
                ps.setBoolean ( 3 , loginAttempt.getSuccessful () );
                ps.setObject ( 4 , loginAttempt.getUuid () );
                ps.executeUpdate ();

            } catch ( SQLException ex ) {
                System.err.println ( "SQLException: " + ex.getMessage () );
                // TODO: Handle exception.
            }
        } catch ( SQLException ex ) {
            System.err.println ( "SQLException on this.fetchConnection: " + ex.getMessage () );
            // TODO: Handle exception.
        }

    }

    public LoginAttempt fetchMostRecentLoginAttempt () {
        // Get database connection.
        // Make prepared statement.
        // Execute query.
        // Transfer pieces of data from ResultSet to new LoginAttempt object.
        // Return object (or null if failure occurred).

        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder ();
        sql.append ( "SELECT * " + " \n" );
        sql.append ( "FROM login_attempt_" + " \n" );
        sql.append ( "ORDER BY when_attempted_ DESC" + " \n" );
        sql.append ( "LIMIT 1" + " \n" );
        sql.append ( ";" + " \n" );

        LoginAttempt loginAttempt = null;
        try ( Connection conn = this.fetchConnection (); ) {
//            System.out.println ( "conn: " + conn );

            try ( Statement stmt = conn.createStatement (); ) {
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery ( sql.toString () );
                int count = 0;
                while ( rs.next () ) {
                    count ++;
                    String userName = rs.getString ( "username_" );
                    java.sql.Timestamp whenWritten = rs.getTimestamp ( "when_attempted_" );
                    Boolean success = rs.getBoolean ( "success_" );
                    UUID uuid = ( UUID ) rs.getObject ( "uuid_" );
                    loginAttempt = new LoginAttempt ( userName , whenWritten.toInstant () , success , uuid );  // Converting from java.sql.Timestamp to java.time.Instant.
                }
                if ( count > 1 ) {
                    // TODO: Handle problem where more than one row returned.
                }

            } catch ( SQLException ex ) {
                System.err.println ( "SQLException: " + ex.getMessage () );
                // TODO: Handle exception.
            }
        } catch ( SQLException ex ) {
            System.err.println ( "SQLException on this.fetchConnection: " + ex.getMessage () );
            // TODO: Handle exception.
        }
        return loginAttempt;
    }

    private Connection fetchConnection () throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            Class.forName ( "org.h2.Driver" );
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            // TODO: Handle exception.
            System.out.println ( "Database failure: " + e );
            return null;
        }

        // Specify a database named 'LoginTracker.mv.db' in the Unix user’s home folder.
        String dbFolderPath = "~/";
        String dbName = "LoginTracker";
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:h2:" + dbFolderPath + dbName;
        String dbUserName = "h2";
        String dbPassword = "pw";

        try {
            // If database does not yet exist, it is automatically created.
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection ( dbUrl , dbUserName , dbPassword );
        } catch ( SQLException ex ) {
            System.out.println ( "SQLException on DriverManager.getConnection: " + ex.getMessage () );
            // TODO: Handle exception when no Connection is made.
        }

        if ( null == conn ) {
            System.out.println ( "Database error. No Connection." );
            // TODO: Handle exception when no Connection is made.
        } else {
            // ELSE got database connection. Normal.
            this.updateDatabaseStructureIfNeedBe ( conn );
        }

        return conn;
    }

    private void updateDatabaseStructureIfNeedBe ( Connection conn ) {
        // Update database structure if needed.

        // 'login_attempt_' Table.
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder ();
        sql.append ( "CREATE TABlE IF NOT EXISTS login_attempt_" + " \n" );
        sql.append ( "(" + " \n" );
        sql.append ( "uuid_ UUID DEFAULT RANDOM_UUID() PRIMARY KEY," + " \n" );  // Primary key, UUID type.
        sql.append ( "when_written_ TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL," + " \n" );  // Record when this record was written to database. Apparently H2 only provides txn start time, not current time.
        sql.append ( "username_ VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(255) NOT NULL," + " \n" );  // User’s name. Case-insensitive.
        sql.append ( "when_attempted_ TIMESTAMP NOT NULL," + " \n" );  // When this login attempt was made.
        sql.append ( "success_ BOOLEAN NOT NULL" + " \n" );  // Did this login attempt succeed or fail?
        sql.append ( ")" + " \n" );
        sql.append ( ";" + " \n" );

        try ( Statement stmt = conn.createStatement () ) {
            stmt.executeUpdate ( sql.toString () );
            stmt.close ();

        } catch ( SQLException ex ) {
            System.err.println ( "SQLException: " + ex.getMessage () );
            // TODO: Handle exception.
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about how much persistence you want, and how much data you have to save. Do you want this information to persist and still be available, after a server reboot?

This will tell you if you need persistent storage (disk, DB, etc.) or if you can maintain it in RAM.

Then, how much data you have, how frequently it will be accessed, etc. will tell you how you should organize it.

Comment: Yes, I want my information to still be available after a server reboot. I want to create a new table where to store the current date, when the user logins. But how do I display the date, which I have stored in my DB as the current date, the next time when the user logs in ?

Comment: When the user logs in and is authenticated, you will query the DB to get some information about the user, including the last login data,